# Saving variables in swing Text field

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I know how to make a text field but I have no idea how to take the info inputted un the text field and save it into a variable. also be able to save only after pressing enter.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class scratch1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);


        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // the panel is not visible in output
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Base:");
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(2); // accepts upto 2 characters
        panel.add(label); // Components Added using Flow Layout
        panel.add(tf);



        
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: [The documentation is your friend.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextField.html)  I’ve been writing Java code for quite a long time, and I still always keep the Java SE documentation on hand.  From that documentation: “How the text field consumes VK_ENTER events depends on whether the text field has any action listeners. If so, then VK_ENTER results in the listeners getting an ActionEvent, and the VK_ENTER event is consumed.”

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access to Java Swing TextField from other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285364/access-to-java-swing-textfield-from-other-class)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, read the comments to understand the code. I hope this code helps you.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

class main {

    static String var; // The text input gets stored in this variable

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Base:");
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(2);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(tf);
           
    
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    
        tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // Action to be performed when "Enter" key is pressed
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                var = tf.getText(); // Getting text input from JTextField(tf)
            }
        });
    }
}
```